# Какое окончание?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь, согласование

"Остал**ось** одна или две главы" или "остал**ись** одна или две главы" - как правильнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь - "остал**ось**". 
Средний род ("Осталось") вообще согласуется с любыми числительными. Особенно в тех случаях, когда "правильное" согласование невозможно по формальным причинам, как в нашем случае.

Answer (score 2):

Мне представляются неверными оба варианта. Причина --- в использовании в данном  выражении имен числительных ОДНА (значение единичности) и ДВЕ (значение множества), каждое из которых требует строго определенной формы числа у личного глагола ОСТАТЬСЯ в значении "оказаться в наличии после чего-либо, например чтения, проработки и т.п": в одном случае --- единственного ОСТАЛАСЬ ОДНА глава, в другом --- множественного ОСТАЛИСЬ ДВЕ главы.

Если же использовать глагол ОСТАТЬСЯ в безличном значении --- ОСТАЛОСЬ, то при нем должен быть инфинитив глагола со значением  действия, которое ОСТАЛОСЬ выполнить( +Дательный субъекта): (Ему, ей, студенту,...) ОСТАЛОСЬ + ПРОЧИТАТЬ (проработать, законспектировать и т.п.) ОДНУ или ДВЕ ГЛАВЫ.

Comment: Вообще-то Розенталь именно этот случай описывает и рекомендует именно средний род. По той самой логике, что согласование (координация) здесь не возможно по формальным причинам.

мм... отвлекают меня. Чуть позже найду источник, если никто не поможет.